# Why should one avoid icing the ulnar nerve directly when icing the elbow?

Tags: tendinopathy, cryotherapy, nerves

I read on http://www.nirschl.com/elbowten.asp:

> Ice is an important element in the healing process and should be used any time signs of inflammation or intense pain are present, no matter how soon or long after the injury. Post exercises ice is also recommended and may be done in conjunction with sensory level electrical stimulation to promote pain and inflammation control. The benefits of ice include a reduction in pain, inflammation, and muscle spasm. Time of ice application ranges from 15-30 minutes. Icing over 30 minutes may cause frost bite. To protect the skin a thin layer of cloth between the skin and ice is worthwhile. **Avoid icing the ulnar nerve directly when icing the elbow.**

Why should one avoid icing the [ulnar nerve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulnar_nerve) directly when icing the elbow?

---

From http://orthoinfo.aaos.org/topic.cfm?topic=a00069:

[image]

From http://www.slideshare.net/sajjadhussainraja/ulnar-nerve-antomy-and-recording-techniques:

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Comment: Me as well, I’m trying to find out whether using either ice or heat can help with pain from ulnar nerve injury in the hand and wrist, every time I do a search on “icing ulnar neuropathy “ I get links to other issues like nerve entrapment or even stuff completely unrelated If someone knows, your feedback would be greatly appreciated Thanks